# Custom Form for Modern UI List item/Content Type

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

Is there a way to customize the layout of the list items/content types in Modern UI ? Right now whenever we click to the title it will open the right panel which I couldn't find a way to customize it.

I could apply an SPFx Extension FieldCustomizer to let the custom page open whenever user click on to the Title field. But still if they using the right mouse context or the ribbon then the panel is still opened instead.

In Classic UI we could simply create custom forms for content type of the list using either SharePoint Designer or provision it with the link to the custom form.

Do you guys know any workaround for this issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this moment there is no way to customize  the standard list form in the modern UI. You could build something yourself but it would be running next to the list rather than on top of it.

Comment: Yes. That is what I'm doing right now. Wish there is an option to change from Panel form to Modal form and allow customization.

Comment: It would definitely be valuable. Have you checked if there is an existing item at the SharePoint UserVoice (https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform) related to this that you could upvote. That's the best way to get the feedback to the SharePoint Product Group.

Comment: I checked and the closest I could find is https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/20474935-field-customizer-evolution-forms-quick-edit-mode which I upvoted with 3 votes.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a workaround ? A SharePoint webpart that reads available list and create new / edit / forms

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-list-form

Comment: That what we have been doing but it's inconvenient since we have to create : a detail lists using office fabric, a create new list item form as modal using office fabric dialog, and the same for edit/view detail list item, finally the deleting function of list items. And last but not least I'm waiting for the pagination on office fabric detail list which is under developed right now.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Is it useful when you just want to customize the New Form and Edit Form maybe ?

Comment: Yeah but users mostly will want to open the custom display form/edit form when they click on the list item. Especially if the form has something like dynamic/repeating table which data is stored in another list.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, there are no built-in customization options for SharePoint forms other than PowerApps, but it does not allow you to design responsive forms or share them with external users. So, I would recommend you to try a paid solution - [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/sharepoint-forms/) which provides a lot of features such as responsive UI, form sets, related items and documents, rich JavaScript framework, and an ability to open forms either in a panel or in a separate window. All those and many other features for a reasonable price.